# How to prevent Lint/Syntax: class definition in method body and Lint/Syntax: unexpected token tEQL in ruby linters

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I'm currently learning ruby so I created this simple class

```rb
class Person
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :age
  
  def initialize(name='Unknow', age, parent_permission = true)
    @id = 222
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end
end
```

but when y ran linters they showed me this two errors

[image]

I reorganized the parameters passed to my initialize method and linters stopped showing those errors, but I'm not really sure which was the mistake or how i should organize parameters in order to prevent this kind of errors. Can someone please help me? just in case it is required I'm using Ruby 3.1.2 and  rubocop 1.34.1

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the `class definition in method body` warning, and I think you've found a bug in RuboCop. The complication relates to optional parameters – these need to come last, otherwise there may be ambiguity in the caller.

If you change it to `age, name='Unknown', parent_permission = true` there is no warning.

RuboCop *should* complain about this, but the warning of `class definition in method body` is wrong and misleading. I would suggest reporting this as bug in the RuboCop GitHub repo.